# How to make this jquery arranger work?

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors

My dilema is this: i have a truck load of photos to insert in a huge table but it`s easier for me to spend a little time on jquery.

I want to insert these photos in divs and a jquery script to make them into a table. this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.coios{
    width:100px;

}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"/></script>


</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#pagination").wrap('<table class="coios">');


$("h1").css({'padding-left':'10px'});                          
$(".one:nth-child(5n)").wrap('<tr class="cinci">');
$(".one:nth-child(n+6)").appendTo(".cinci");
$(".one").wrap('<td>'); 

});
</script>



<div id="pagination">

<div class="one">
<h1>test1</h1>
<img src="http://www.salice.ro/img/produse/thumbs/lyMuRHalbspan_140.jpg" /></img>

</div>

<div class="one">
<h1>test2</h1>
<img src="http://www.salice.ro/img/produse/thumbs/26tb2U125albastru.jpg" /></img>

</div>

<div class="one">
<h1>test3</h1>
<img src="http://www.salice.ro/img/produse/thumbs/26tb2U125albastru.jpg" /></img>

</div>
<div class="one">
<h1>test4</h1>
<img src="http://www.salice.ro/img/produse/thumbs/26tb2U125albastru.jpg" /></img>

</div>
<div class="one">
<h1>test5</h1>
<img src="http://www.salice.ro/img/produse/thumbs/26tb2U125albastru.jpg" /></img>

</div>

<div class="one">
<h1>test6</h1>
<img src="http://www.salice.ro/img/produse/thumbs/26tb2U125albastru.jpg" /></img>

</div>

<div class="one">
<h1>test7</h1>
<img src="http://www.salice.ro/img/produse/thumbs/26tb2U125albastru.jpg" /></img>

</div>

<div class="one">
<h1>test8</h1>
<img src="http://www.salice.ro/img/produse/thumbs/26tb2U125albastru.jpg" /></img>

</div>

<div class="one">
<h1>test9</h1>
<img src="http://www.salice.ro/img/produse/thumbs/26tb2U125albastru.jpg" /></img>

</div>


<div class="one">
<h1>test10</h1>
<img src="http://www.salice.ro/img/produse/thumbs/26tb2U125albastru.jpg" /></img>

</div>


<div class="one">
<h1>test11</h1>
<img src="http://www.salice.ro/img/produse/thumbs/26tb2U125albastru.jpg" /></img>

</div>


</div> <!--pagination-->




</body>
</html>
```

look what happens from test9 how can I solve this problem .

Thanks for your help

Comment: Protip: Rather than expect everyone else to try to replicate your problem, spend 5 minutes creating a good http://www.jsfiddle.net which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rwdUM/

Comment: ok I promise next time I will make one I promise

Comment: You have no elements with id "pagination"!?!?

Comment: @stian.net - except the very first element after the closing script tag :D

Comment: lol.. Was it edited or was I blind?

Comment: @stian.net - nope, no edit to that. Seek opthalmic advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that instead of trying to wrap each item, you dynamically build up the table and replace the original div. Something like this:

```
var $table = $('<table class="coios"></table>'); // create a new table
var $tr = null;

$('.one').each(function(i,e){ // loop each ".one" element (i is the index, e is the element)

    if((i%5) == 0){ // create a new tr on iteration 1, 6, 11 etc
         $tr = $('<tr class="cinci"></tr>');
    }   

    var $td = $('<td></td>'); // create a new td
    $td.append(e); // append the current ".one" element to the td
    $tr.append($td); // append the td to the current tr

    if((i%5) == 0){ // make sure if we've created a new tr to append it to the table
         $table.append($tr);   
    }
});

$("#pagination").replaceWith($table); // replace the "#pagination" element with our new table
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/rwdUM/2/

Comment: could you explain what you did step by step pls :D